# configure spring loggers with respect to application for multi module deployment

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, logging, log4j

Spring framework logs are not logged as per the application specific log files in a multi module war files deployment

This is on a tomcat server, I have deployed 4 war files , and each log file needs to write the application specific logs into their respective application log file and not to a common log file .Lets say
1. app A --> A.log
2. app B --> B.log  and so on.

[log4j xml config which is used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EVKM.png)
I use log4j appenders and the application is segragted based on package name as highlighted below

Expected result :  A.log file must have all the logs {including the spring framework/aop/rest template of that particular application}

Actual result: A.log file only has application based logger, all the spring framework logs are not logged into A.log, instead it logs into catalina.log